# Ionic Firebase Auth Popup Window Closes Immediately

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, facebook-authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm following the Facebook Auth tutorial on the Firebase website.  You can see it here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/ionic/guide.html

```
$scope.login = function() {
Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook").then(function(authData) {
  // User successfully logged in
}).catch(function(error) {
  if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
    Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
      // User successfully logged in. We can log to the console
      // since we’re using a popup here
      console.log(authData);
    });
  } else {
    // Another error occurred
    console.log(error);
  }
});
};
```

My issue is that I am correctly receiving the TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE error and I am getting to the following line of code

```
Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup("facebook").then(function(authData) {
  // do stuff with the authData
})
```

But, when I run on my device or in emulator, the popup window that is coming from the InAppBrowser Plugin closes immediately and doesn't allow me to enter any of my credentials.

EDIT

Two things to note.  First, with the above code auth does not work when done via the browser.  So, if I do `ionic serve` and try to login nothing happens except that I see the url change briefly to `http://localhost:8100/#/login&__firebase_request_key=0wRrfF07Ojg1PmJXNX1OsvrRFR2Q1LGj`
 but then it goes back to `http://localhost:8100/#/login`

Secondly, when I build the project via Xocde and run on my device, the InAppBrowser plugin seems to no longer be closing right away but instead freezes with a white screen.  The logs in Xcode show the following

`THREAD WARNING: ['InAppBrowser'] took '79.103027' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
webView:didFailLoadWithError - -1200: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.`

EDIT 2

Looks like the above issues with SSL error was because of an unrelated bug with upgrading to ios 9.  I've since corrected those issues and now I'm back to the original.  Except now the InAppBrowser window doesn't even open, I'm still hitting the catch block with TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly how I fixed this issue.  Hard to isolate what was breaking originally and what was breaking due to ios 9 upgrades.  But, I've been able to fix the issue.  I started by blowing away the `/ios` and `/android` folders inside of `/platforms`.  I also deleted all the plugins from the `/plugins` folder.

Then I added back ios and android platforms.  Then I added back the plugins.  Then I followed the steps found in these 2 blog posts modifying your app to be ios 9 compliment.

http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/

http://blog.ionic.io/preparing-for-ios-9/